# What are SQLite error codes doing in winerror.h?

Tags: winapi

In Windows SDK v.10.0.14393.0, in winerror.h, there is a SQLite section, line 57116 and below. Is SQLite officially a part of Win32 now?

EDIT: there's a winsqlite3.h under um\winsqlite, introduced some time between SDK v.10.0.10240.0 and v.10.0.10586.0. And winsqlite3.lib under um.

EDIT: changed an existing Win32 application to use that, works like a charm. Needed to redefine `_WIN32_WINNT` to 0xa00 though - explicitly targeting Windows 10.

Comment: Windows is a mess.

Comment: No, but they may have put it there for some future update.  There 's a possibility that it's used by an internal component as well.This SDK is old btw.  You may want to remove the line references from the question.

Comment: That's pretty interesting, it has been available for a while: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/03/data-access-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp-apps/

Comment: @Luis: make an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for noticing, because it's interesting!

Microsoft made it part of the Windows 10 Anniversary Edition and it's available for UWP apps: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/03/data-access-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp-apps/

Comment: It's equally available for Win32 apps. `#include <winsqlite/winsqlite3.h>` and link to winsqlite3.lib.